# ClickOnce deployment - the application requires that an assembly is installed in the GAC

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce

I have created a C# Windows Forms application and then created a ClickOnce setup:

- I'm using zxing [Zxing Home](https://zxingnet.codeplex.com/).
- Copy local is true
- *Embed interop types* is false. If turned true it gives error "Cannot embed interop types from assembly zxing"

The error above is:

> Unable to install or run the application the application requires that zxing version 0.14.0.0 to be installed in the GAC first

What is the solution?

Is there an alternative other than ClickOnce? (Doing the update function.)

Comment: Could you install zxing (in the GAC) before you do your click-once install?

Comment: How (i got it using NuGet)? but that means that i have to install it at the client ? and that means that i will do the same if i used a new dll ?

Comment: Did you tried include zxing required assemblies in your ClickOnce Setup? Go to "Application Files" > "Publish Status" set to Include

Comment: thank you i discovered the problem it was the version of the dll the NuGet downloads version 16 the error is asking for version 14 i had to download the specific version 14